# C++ on ubuntu hello world

Tags: c++, ubuntu-15.04

I'm trying to write my first code on ubuntu terminal using c++ 
.I created a new cpp file named aaa by

```
"nano aaa.cpp"
```

then inside I wrote

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, car** argv)
{
   cout << "hello" << endl;
   return 0; 
}
```

i saved and got out but when i  tried typing

```
g++ aaa.cpp
```

I got the error

**error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
    cout << "hello" << endl;**

where did I go wrong 
I tried

```
$ sudo apt-get remove g++ libstdc++-6.4.7-dev
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential g++-multilib
```

but it was no good

### any help?

Comment: Do you not need `#include` rather than `include`

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n`' ends a line. But `#include <iomanip>` will get you the declaration for `std::endl`.

Comment: @NickA - that would leave `std::cout` undefined, as well. It's clearly a typo in the example code, not the original.

Comment: The first error should be something like `error: ‘include’ does not name a type \n include<iostream>`, and you should fix it first.

Comment: @Pete Becker `endl` is also a member of `ostream` so including `iostream` would already include `endl`.  Including `iomanip` would be no help.

Comment: There is another typo: `car` -> `char`.

Comment: The `main()` signature also has an error which I fixed in my answer below which already received two generous downvotes.

Comment: The signature for main should be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, not `int main(int argc, car** argv)` as you wrote here.

Comment: @NickA - you're right, `<iostream>` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylistically, I prefer to be explicit:  `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

This also fixes a tyo of yours:  `char`, not `car` and repairs the `#include`.

This works as expected:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o foo2 foo2.cpp
$ ./foo2
hello
$
```

If you wanted to, you could also use

```
using namespace std;
```

but as stated, I prefer to more explicit form.

*Edit:* Nothing as much fun as debating the beancounters.  OP question is likely having _another error he is not sharing.  His code, repaired for `char` actually builds:

```
$ cat foo3.cpp 
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  cout << "hello" << endl;
  return 0; 
}
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o foo3 foo3.cpp
$ ./foo3
hello
$
```

Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4.0

Comment: Fun morning. Two drive-by downvotes without comments?  Awesome.

Comment: Well, you haven't answered the question being asked here.

Comment: Yes I did: `std::endl`. Explicit reference.

Comment: OK I see. But `using std::endl;` takes care of that, so this doesn't present a solution (except for the typo in the main function parameters.)

Comment: Doesn't explain his compiler error.  He _must_ have another one.

Comment: Right. Because there is not enough information in the question. Also, your suggestion of `using namespace std;` is unnecessary and worse than what OP already has.

Comment: You are a real treasure. I mentioned it for fscking completeness and do not use it my answer.

Comment: And then you wonder why people don't leave comments when they down-vote.

Comment: You are effing wrong.  Whether to selectively include (`using std::foo`) or to explicitly refer (`std::foo`) is equivalent.  I don;t like your suggestion as it bloats the top-part of the file.   I _like_ the explicit reference especially when I work with multiple namespaces.

Comment: Also real impressive that you now admit that you were wrong earlier, yet don't lift the downvote. Stay classy, San Diego.

Comment: Anyway, the question was low quality and I voted for it to be closed.  May as well be deleted.

Comment: I wasn't wrong, and I didn't admit any such thing. I haven't changed my judgment of your answer, although I agree with your coding style suggestion. But that is tangential to the problem reported here.

Comment: So you confirm that you can't read, or don't understand conditionals. Else you would have seen my `If you wanted to ...but I prefer to more explicit form.` (Which needs a `s/to/the/` ...)

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have the tools you need to be able to compile a C++ code on Ubuntu. For that run the following code in the command line :
This line will install all the basic stuff you need for compiling a C++ code, it will install C, C++, and make.

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now that you have all you need, I will suggere to explicetely using **std::cout / std::endl** . That way you don't import all the stuff available under the namespace **std** that you are not using. Using std::cout / std::endl shows clearly the origin the instance you are using.
Notice : you have an error in the main function argument, namely : *car*, it should be **char**

```
#include<iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
   return 0; 
}
```

Now you can compile and run your code this way :
in this example I'm calling the executable file "hello"

```
g++ -Wall -o hello aaa.cpp
./hello
```